# Eclipse feature, force a plugin version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pde

We have a dependency for a 3rd party library.
org.apache.batik.css

We use the Eclipse ORBIT repo, to get 3rd party plugin in a .target configuration file.

The repo contains two versions:

org.apache.batik.css   (source)    1.6.0
 org.apache.batik.css   (source)    1.7.0

When I look in the Eclipse Target View, I can see both versions.

We have a product which has a feature for this plugin. The product complaints the plugin is not 
available (The check button in the .product editor) to one of the dependents of this plugin.

> .product
>
> > org.apache (Feature)
> >
> > > org.apache.batik.css
> >
> > org.eclipse.e4.rcp (Feature)
> >
> > > requires org.apache.batik.css (1.6.0)

How can I force the feature org.apache, holding this plugin to use 1.6.0 ? I have tried to set the version 
in feature.xml like this, but still it complaints?

```
(tags ommitted). 

         id="org.apache.batik.css"
         download-size="0"
         install-size="0"
         version="1.6.0.v201011041432"
         unpack="false"
```

I found a way, by making the selection of the correct plugin in the .target file, but I'd rather force the correct plugin version in a feature.

Thank You,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Eclipse interprets a single version as a minimum version. In your case, you need to specify a version range, that only includes that particular version `[1.6.0.v201011041432,1.6.0.v201011041432]`

Take a look at [this blog post](http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/manifestmf-and-featurexml), which explains it pretty nicely.